# Why I can't determine locatoin on some devices?

Tags: android, location, android-location

Good day. I learnt all about LocationListener and looked through different examples - but every time some tests on different devices make me upset. 
So, I ask you for help.
Trouble-devices: Samsung Galaxy S1, Galaxy fit, htc one v, HTC Incredible S,  Pipo Smart S1 and some else.
NoProblem-device: Samsung Galaxy S3. Help :)

Current implementation:

```
public class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener
{
    // Current myLocation
    private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
    private boolean mLocationEnabled = false;
    private volatile Location mLocation;
    private LocationListener locationListener;
    private volatile boolean locationChanged = false;
    //interface implementation Runnable which called UI methods
    private LocationRunnable runnable = null;


    public LocationListener(Context context, LocationRunnable runnable)
    {
        this.runnable = runnable;
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mLocation = null;
    }

    public boolean enableMyLocation()
    {
        mLocationEnabled = true;
        List<String> mProviders = mLocationManager.getProviders(true);

        if (mProviders.size() > 0)
        {
            locationListener = this;
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, locationListener);

        }

        //start background process to count 30 secs
        new TimeOut().execute();
        return false;
    }

    public void disabledMyLocation()
    {
        if (mLocationManager != null)
            mLocationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }


    private class TimeOut extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
                long sec = System.currentTimeMillis();
               //here we count 30 secs and if method onLocationChanged wasn't run before, start runnable here
                while (!locationChanged && System.currentTimeMillis() - sec < 30 * 1000)
                {}
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void p)
        {
            if (!locationChanged)
            {
                runnable.setLocation(mLocation);
                runnable.run();
            }

        //cancel update
            mLocationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
        }
    }




    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
     //if location is OK so call UI changing
        mLocation = location;
        locationChanged = true;
        runnable.setLocation(location);
        runnable.run();
        //cancel update
        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
    }

}
```

Comment: On the devices you have problems with, do you have at least one location service enabled?

Comment: yes, its checked, and  show alet dilog

Comment: Why do you think you should be able to get a network-based location in less than 30 seconds? You must have a working Internet connection to get a network-based location.